# Keyboard layout changed unexpectedly

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

So I had initially set my keyboard to Switzerland (French- Macintosh) which worked almost on point (some commands did not correspond), but a few days ago, I woke up to a keyboard layout that was completely different (I think the one classically used in Windows OS, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>=`!` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>=`@` etc.), despite the same layout being selected and used.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've the latest version of Ubuntu (running on VirtualBox).

Screenshot keyboard:
[image: Screenshot keyboard]

Screenshot settings page:
[image: Screenshot settings page]

Comment: could you add a sreenshot of  the whole window where you can see that "Switzerland (French- Macintosh)" is selected?

Comment: Hey tatsu, thanks for your reply. Find the screenshots included. So by itself I suppose the computer responds correctly to the keyboard that's displayed. The issue is that it wasn't like that when I first used it (and it is not supposed to be as shown either). Is it a recent update that modified keyboard layouts accidentally or something?

Comment: so the layout doesn't correspond to what you expect from French (Switzerland, Macintosh)? yes it's possible the schematic was out of date compared to international norms. I suggest you start looking among the French choices for the one that suits you best if the layout you showed in the picture is not the one you want. "alternate french" (first french) choice has the symbols first and numbers you have to access with shift, which, I imagine, is what you want.

Comment: Yes it is not what I expect. I also just realized that all keyboards, when i display them, have the same layout that I currently have (i.e. even if I try an AZERTY I see the qwerty that I currently use). I guess it is a system-wide problem and not specific to my keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so by running

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

(which I had tried before), I needed to select the French-Switzerland default package, as the Macintosh one does not work ('cannot find "fr_mac" in "macintosh_vndr/ch".'). Better than before at least.